# How to really prevent an element from being put into the DOM with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Let's say you have the following code to display some products images:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in products">
    <img ng-src="/images/{{p.img}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now let's say some products unfortunately don't have images, you may fix that with:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in products">
    <img ng-hide="p.img==undefined" ng-src="/images/{{p.img}}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now go to the "network" tab of firebug or chrome developer tools and check for the images download -- you will see errors, because the browser still tried to download the non-existent image. It's hidden and the users won't notice, but of course it's bad: bad practice, bad for server performance, bad bad bad...

What is the correct "angular" solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to @Arun's solution is to use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) or [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) (available in v1.1.5), which add/remove DOM elements, unlike ng-hide/ng-show:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in products">
    <span ng-switch="p.img==undefined">
      <img ng-switch-when="false" ng-src="/images/{{p.img}}"/>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See @Rob's answer for an example using ng-if.

Comment: Tip: According to Misko at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L35 : ngShow and ngHide are going to do change dom instead of using `display: none;`

Comment: @Umur - I think you mean the ngIf directive available in 1.1.5. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2f96fbd17577685bc013a4f7ced06664af253944

Comment: @Rob, It has changed since, but take a look at the source code from a couple of months ago: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/11f712bc3e310302eb2e8691cf6d110bdcde1810/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L101

Answer (score 3):

With version 1.1.5 you can use ng-if as @Abilash suggests:

```
<img ng-if="p.img" ng-src="/images/{{p.img}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="p in products | imgsrc">
        {{p.img}}
        <img ng-src="/images/{{p.img}}"/>
    </li>
</ul>


app.filter('imgsrc', function(){
    return function(data){
        var a = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function(v, i){
            if(v.img){
                a.push(v);
            }
        });
        return a;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MX7xm/2/)

Comment: Why not ui-if which is defined in angular-ui.js?

Comment: Maybe because it is another library?