# AngularJS 1.0.7 HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 app with a code like this:

```
<img ng-show="selectType != null" 
     ng-src="//domain/img/boat_types/{{selectType.name}}.jpg" 
     style="margin-left: 175px; height: 200px; width: 200px" 
     class="media-object img-circle"/>
```

As the image is only displayed when selectType is not null, the other times I´m getting this error in the browser console.

```
GET http://domain/img/boat_types/.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

Can I avoid this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, and everything to do with who serves up that image

Comment: `ng-if="selectType != null"` - with `ng-if` the element won't be added to the DOM - so no bad request occurs

Comment: What back-end are you using? asp.net? node? ror? I'm asking because this 403 error has nothing to do with Angular per say.

Comment: `http://domain/img/boat_types/.jpg 403 (Forbidden)` it looks as `selectType.name` is empty string?

Comment: @tymeJV Your approach looks good, but I forgot the detail that my AngularJS version is 1.0.7. I think I have not an ng-if. I can´t migrate right now, so any workaround?

Comment: Two workaround were provided in the answer below: one using a default path, one using ng-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I avoid this?

**Yes**, by replacing `ng-show` by `ng-if`.

---

```
<img ng-if="typeof selectType.name!=='undefined'" 
 ng-src="//domain/img/boat_types/{{selectType.name}}.jpg" 
 style="margin-left: 175px; height: 200px; width: 200px" 
 class="media-object img-circle"/>
```

should work. Replace `ng-show` by `ng-if`, so the directive will not compile if `selectType.name` does not exist.

---

- When you use `ng-show`, the directive compiles - whether the condition is met or not - but does not show if the condition is not met. It means it will try to fetch a non-existent image, hence the error message.
- With `ng-if`, if the condition is not met, there will be not compiling, and no error.

---

**EDIT: Workaround for an older version of angularjs, which does not have `ng-if`**:

A default path could be set, that would point to an existing, low-weight image.

Replace `ng-src="//domain/img/boat_types/{{selectType.name}}.jpg"` by `ng-src="mysrc"` in your view.

then define a default path for your image in your controller/directive:

```
$scope.mysrc=(typeof selectType.name!=='undefined')?"//domain/img/boat_types/"+$scope.selectType.name+".jpg":"path/to/my/low/weight/default/image.jpg";
```

So, if the condition is not met, the directive can compile by filling `$scope.mysrc` with the default image path, which does not return an error.

The path to the default image is just there to prevent the error message. The default image will be fetched, but never actually displayed.

---

**EDIT: for versions of angularjs that have ng-switch, there is yet another workaround**, according to this post:

[How to really prevent an element from being put into the DOM with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451138/how-to-really-prevent-an-element-from-being-put-into-the-dom-with-angularjs)

In your case, you could use `ng-switch` this way:

```
<span ng-switch="typeof selectType.name==='undefined'">
  <img ng-switch-when="false" ng-src="//domain/img/boat_types/{{selectType.name}}.jpg"/>
</span>
```

Comment: Your approach looks good, but I forgot the detail that my AngularJS version is 1.0.7. I think I have not an ng-if. I can´t migrate right now, so any workaround.

Comment: Strange, but should work. Got it, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: quick and dirty, it's just a hack until you can use a more recent version of angular.js

Comment: @Rober have you had a chance to try the workarounds?

Comment: I rather your second approach. Just one note: This condition typeof selectType.name==='undefined' didn´t work for me. I got a javascript error. I used: selectType == null